# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'BrowserWindow' of undefined in angular version 10 and electron version 10 and ngx-electron 2.2.0

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, desktop-application

l have been trying to solve this error for the last 2 to 3 days.
I have a bigger program that gave me that so reproduced the error.

**Steps to reproduce the error.**

1. Install the latest version of **angular cli**   **version 10 to be precise**.
2. Create an angular new project with **ng new atatest**.. Mine I called **atatest**.
3. Install the latest version of **electron** which is **version 10**.
4. Install the latest version of **ngx-electron** that is **version 2.2.0**
5. Create a main.js in the root directory of the project and populate it with the electron boiler plate
   code.
6. I added **`import { NgxElectronModule } from 'ngx-electron';`** in the **app.module.ts** and included
   it in the **NgModule.imports**.
7. In the **app.component.ts** do the following:
   i. Add **ElectronService**  **`import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';`**

   ii. Then in the ***app.component.ts*** add the following:

```js
brower: any;
 constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService) {
 this.browse = this._electronService.remote.BrowserWindow;
}
```

```
  -> At this point I got: **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'BrowserWindow' of null** which 
     also was the same when I tried it with any instance of electron including require which was 
     **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of null**
```

8. With that error I added **nodeItegration to true** in the main process that is **main.js**.
9. With that I  got the following error:
   **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'BrowserWindow' of undefined**
10. I also tried to require electron in the index.html as the following but got the same error:

```
<script> const electron = require('electron'); </script>
```

11. I have written apps in the past in angular and electron and have never seen such a big problem. The
    files are as follows:

a. Then the **app.module.ts** is:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    
    
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgxElectronModule } from 'ngx-electron';
    
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NgxElectronModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

b. The **app.component.ts** is:

```js
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        
        import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';
        
        @Component({
        
          selector: 'app-root',
        
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
        
        })
        export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
        
          browse: any;
        
          constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService){
        
           this.browse = this._electronService.remote.BrowserWindow;
        
          }
        
          title = 'atatest';
        
            launch(){
        
              let win: any;
        
              win = new this.browse({
        
                 width: 800,
        
                 height: 600
        
              });
        
              win.loadURL('https://google.com');
        
            }
        
        ngOnInit(){
        
           this.launch();
        
        }
        
        }
```

12. ln the package.json

```json
       {
  "name": "atatest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron ."
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.5",
    "electron": "^10.1.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-electron": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

13.In the **main.js** file we have:

```js
    const { app, BrowserWindow } = require ('electron');
    const path = require ('path');
    const url = require('url');
    
    let win;
     function createWindow(){
         //create the browser window
         win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800,
                                  height: 600,
                                   webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}
                                })
    
         win.loadURL(url.format({
             pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/atatest/index.html'),
             protocol: 'file:',
             slashes: true,
             webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}
         }))
    
           // Open the DevTools optionally:
       win.webContents.openDevTools()
    
       win.on('closed', ()=>{
           win =null;
       })
    }
    
    app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that the **Electron version 10** ***has remote disabled by default***. l identified it by creating a new angular project and installing electron version 9 instead of 10.

I version 10 **remote is disabled by default**. You have to enable it manually in the electron **entry file** in my case **main.js** by **setting enableRemoteModule to true** in the **webPreferences** works like a charm and the error goes. The code is therefore modified as follows:

`win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800,
height: 600,
webPreferences: {
nodeIntegration: true,
enableRemoteModule: true
}
})`